# using imap get href

Tags: php, html, imap

I'm using the following:

```
foreach($emails as $email_number) {
    $output = '';
    // get information specific to this email 
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
```

if I print $message I get the link displayed.  Is there a way to see the actual address?

Note: if i echo $message it displays as a link but gives me a file not found
      if i echo quoted_printable_decode($message) it displays as a link and works.  What I need is to see the actual href inside php

Comment: What link/address?

Comment: the link is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46-6LG0Io2iSlF1YTdoODdLbFU/view

Comment: You'll have to parse the contents of `$message`.

Comment: Could you generate an iframe with your link in it, after you've parsed out your message to get the link?

Comment: You mean there is a link somewhere in the e-mail? Is the format of the e-mail always the same (e.g. sent by a script) or are the e-mails user-generated? If the former, can you provide an example of the message as fetched? If the latter, you'll probably have tu use a MIME parser to decode the whole e-mail and recursively walk through all parts and check their contents, possibly using an HTML parser in some cases...